# It is possible to use a custom IP with the geolocation feature of Google Chrome?

Tags: php, javascript, html

today i tested the geolocation system implement by google on Chrome, with this page: http://www.browsergeolocation.com/ , the think is, is possible to use this service but without my ip?, i mean, using other ip to retrive the geo info.

PS 1: I know the are many sites that offer iptogeo services, but they only give you a very general address. This particular service gave not only the country and the state, it gave even the street!

PS 2: I post this question here because i know the solution may be on code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W3C,

> The Geolocation API must be agnostic
>   to the underlying sources of location
>   information.

So no, given that the source might be an onboard GPS or triangulation based on on nearby SSIDs, it cannot be done with only an IP. You'd anyway only get as good result as from the iptogeo services if it worked, as Google can't reach into my computer and read my GPS. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use it for other peoples IP. The site uses location aware browsing which is a browser feature and needs to be authorized by the user. The user's browser also may provide additional information that only they have access too.

You can read more about location aware browsing at [Geolocation in Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/geolocation/). This page is for firefox, but describes some important things.

FYI the accuracy for my result was limited to just my city.